# Error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 22

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to fix this for two days and I couldnt.
I know why the code happens but Im not sure where.
or why its happening...

This has to be done in PLSQL
its a homework assignment.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE

  V_IDNO      PAYDATA1.IDNO%TYPE;
  V_NAME      PAYDATA1.NAME%TYPE;
  V_SAL       PAYDATA1.SALARY%TYPE;
  V_JOB       PAYDATA1.JOBCODE%TYPE;
  V_PAY       PAYDATA1.PAYHR%TYPE;
  V_IDNO1     PAYTRAN1.IDNO%TYPE;
  V_HOURSWK   PAYTRAN1.HOURSWK%TYPE; 
  V_HOURS     HOURSWKD.HOURSWK%TYPE; 

  V_CHECK    NUMBER(10);
CURSOR paydata_cursor IS
     SELECT IDNO, NAME, JOBCODE, SALARY, PAYHR FROM PAYDATA1
     ORDER BY IDNO;
CURSOR paytran_cursor IS
     SELECT IDNO, HOURSWK FROM PAYTRAN1
     WHERE V_IDNO = IDNO
     order by IDNO;
BEGIN
OPEN paydata_cursor;
LOOP
FETCH paydata_cursor INTO V_IDNO, V_NAME, V_CHECK, V_JOB, V_PAY;
EXIT WHEN paydata_cursor%NOTFOUND;

IF V_SAL > 0 THEN
V_CHECK := V_SAL / 52;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_IDNO|| ' HAS A CHECK FOR: '||V_CHECK);

END IF;

IF V_SAL = 0 AND V_HOURSWK < 41 THEN
V_CHECK := V_PAY * V_HOURS;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_IDNO|| ' HAS A CHECK FOR: '||V_CHECK);

ELSIF V_SAL = 0 AND V_HOURSWK > 40 THEN
V_CHECK := V_PAY * V_HOURS;
V_CHECK := V_SAL + ((V_HOURSWK * 1.5) * (V_HOURSWK - 40));

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_IDNO|| ' HAS A CHECK FOR: '||V_CHECK);

END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE paydata_cursor;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

IM GETTING THIS ERROR, TRIED TO FIX IT ALL DAY AND COULDN’T. ANY ADVICE?

```
SQL> @ CURSOR5
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 22
```

Comment: is it a stored procedure you are trying to write.

Comment: Cant we simply make a join between PAYDATA1 and PAYTRAN1 table ?

Answer (score 2):

I can see a few issues with your code but without knowing much more info it's difficult to diagnose...but I'll try:

It looks like you're selecting into the wrong variables when opening your cursor.

You also haven't opened your `paytran_cursor` anywhere. You can add that code yourself but until you do, your check of `V_HOURSWK` won't be very useful etc.

Try this instead:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE

  V_IDNO      PAYDATA1.IDNO%TYPE;
  V_NAME      PAYDATA1.NAME%TYPE;
  V_SAL       PAYDATA1.SALARY%TYPE;
  V_JOB       PAYDATA1.JOBCODE%TYPE;
  V_PAY       PAYDATA1.PAYHR%TYPE;
  V_IDNO1     PAYTRAN1.IDNO%TYPE;
  V_HOURSWK   PAYTRAN1.HOURSWK%TYPE; 
  V_HOURS     HOURSWKD.HOURSWK%TYPE; 

  V_CHECK    NUMBER(10);
CURSOR paydata_cursor IS
     SELECT IDNO, NAME, JOBCODE, SALARY, PAYHR 
       FROM PAYDATA1
      ORDER BY IDNO;
CURSOR paytran_cursor IS
     SELECT IDNO, HOURSWK 
       FROM PAYTRAN1
      WHERE V_IDNO = IDNO
      order by IDNO;
BEGIN
  OPEN paydata_cursor;
  LOOP
    -- Changed the variables you were selecting into
    FETCH paydata_cursor INTO V_IDNO, V_NAME, V_JOB, V_SAL, V_PAY;
    EXIT WHEN paydata_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    IF V_SAL > 0 
    THEN
      V_CHECK := V_SAL / 52;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_IDNO|| ' HAS A CHECK FOR: '||V_CHECK);
    END IF;

    IF V_SAL = 0 AND V_HOURSWK < 41 
    THEN
      V_CHECK := V_PAY * V_HOURS;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_IDNO|| ' HAS A CHECK FOR: '||V_CHECK);
    ELSIF V_SAL = 0 AND V_HOURSWK > 40 
    THEN
      V_CHECK := V_PAY * V_HOURS;
      V_CHECK := V_SAL + ((V_HOURSWK * 1.5) * (V_HOURSWK - 40));

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_IDNO|| ' HAS A CHECK FOR: '||V_CHECK);
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE paydata_cursor;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

I have tried to guess what you are trying to do with your code and think that this below might go some way to fixing your issues in a slightly more efficient manner:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  --
  c_max_hours CONSTANT NUMBER := 40;
  --
  -- N.B.: I have assumed that there may be more than one entry per IDNO for 
  -- hours worked, if this is not the case then you can remove the SUM() and 
  -- the GROUP BY clause
  --
  CURSOR pay_cursor
  IS
    SELECT IDNO, 
           NAME, 
           JOBCODE, 
           SALARY, 
           PAYHR,
           SUM(HOURSWK) AS HOURS_WORKED
      FROM PAYDATA1
      JOIN PAYTRAN1 USING (IDNO)
     GROUP BY IDNO, 
              NAME, 
              JOBCODE, 
              SALARY, 
              PAYHR;
  --
  V_CHECK     NUMBER;
  pay_record  pay_cursor%ROWTYPE;
  --
BEGIN
  -- Depending on the rows in your cursor you might want to increase the output buffer for DBMS_OUTPUT
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
  --
  OPEN pay_cursor;
  LOOP
    -- Fetch the data into your cursor rowtype variable
    FETCH paydata_cursor INTO pay_record;
    EXIT WHEN pay_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    --
    -- ASSUMPTION: salary is not NULL (i.e. 0 or more).
    --
    IF pay_record.salary > 0 
    THEN
      V_CHECK := pay_record.salary / 52;
    ELSE
      --
      -- Salary must be zero
      --
      IF pay_record.hours_worked <= c_max_hours 
      THEN
        V_CHECK := pay_record.payhr * pay_record.hours_worked;
      ELSE
        -- Must be > c_max_hours 
        V_CHECK := pay_record.payhr * pay_record.hours_worked;
        V_CHECK := pay_record.salary + ((pay_record.hours_worked * 1.5) * (pay_record.hours_worked - 40));
      END IF;
    END IF;

    --
    -- Output your result
    --
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pay_record.idno|| ' HAS A CHECK FOR: '||V_CHECK);

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE paydata_cursor;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others
  THEN
    -- Close the cursor if it is still open
    IF pay_cursor%ISOPEN
    THEN 
      CLOSE pay_cursor;
    END IF;
    -- Re-raise the error
    RAISE;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

I hope it's useful.
P.S. I couldn't check this in a real environment as I'm not at my usual PC so apologies for any syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you, you guys were great and this fixed my issues.

Comment: @FagnerSchuindtCaetano, if it fixed your issue, could you please mark the answer as correct as it helps with feedback etc. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your column `paydata1.JOBCODE` is not a number 
and in this code `FETCH paydata_cursor INTO V_IDNO, V_NAME, V_CHECK, V_JOB, V_PAY;` you are assigning it to V_CHECK which is number

Change the order like this: `FETCH paydata_cursor INTO V_IDNO, V_NAME, V_JOB, V_CHECK,  V_PAY;` and it should work but ensure that `paydata1.salary` is a number

Also i am not sure when you have declared `V_SAL` then why are you using `V_CHECK` in this cursor fetch.

Answer (score 1):

at line 13 when you are defining your cursor paydata_cursor as columns like

SELECT IDNO, NAME, JOBCODE, SALARY, PAYHR FROM PAYDATA1
     ORDER BY IDNO;
column sequence IDNO, NAME, JOBCODE, SALARY, PAYHR

but in line 23 i.e.

FETCH paydata_cursor INTO V_IDNO, V_NAME, V_CHECK, V_JOB, V_PAY;
you are actually fetching the columns like this

IDNO, NAME, JOBCODE, SALARY, PAYHR into 
V_IDNO, V_NAME, V_CHECK, V_JOB, V_PAY

that means JOBCODE is going into V_CHECK
and SALARY is going into V_JOB
since salary must be number and v_check must be varchar

i think this is why u r getting this error

Thanks 
Sid